# Medium platform - how do you withdraw your draft article from consideration at a publication?

Tags: publishing, blog, submitting-work, freelance, medium-platform

I am new to Medium and submitted a link of my draft article to a Medium publication 4 days ago (via an online form). I have not heard back from the editor with a decision. I want to submit the link of the draft article to a different publication. How do I withdraw the draft article from consideration at the current publication?

Comment: @Matt I don't understand your comment. Are you suggesting Medium is a scam? It's the biggest blogging site in the world.

Comment: @S. Mitchell You're right, seems I was extremely unlucky. I visited the site at a time when there was some kind of network issue. Now I see a privacy policy banner, I find legal information etc. All this wasn't there a few hours ago. I've just deleted my previous comment as it's become obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter your medium Draft, you should see in the three dot menu at the top (***) an option called “remove from publication”.
This will remove your draft from the pub’s queue. This is also how you remove already published pieces from a publication.

Make sure that an editor has not seen your draft yet. It will be somewhat rude to remove it after an editor worked in it.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an answer to your question in the Medium Help Center. I assume it is something very few people want to do.

It can take time for a publication to see if they want to publish your work. One publication, for example, says allow at least two weeks. Check out their contribution guidelines. One publisher I know of has a full-time job. Medium is a part-time hobby so he doesn't review drafts immediately. I assume other people go on holidays occasionally or get sick.

You could simply delete your draft and then re-publish it.